# uninstall python 3 from macOS

Tags: python-3.x

I have python3 install in 3 locations

- `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`
- `/usr/local/bin/python3`
- `/usr/bin/python3`

is it possible to complete uninstall python3 and reinstall it with only one version? Also, can I override the Python 2 that is installed on my Mac?